# Appwrite Local Setup - Exceeding User Limit Despite Unlimited Setting in Dashboard

Tags: flutter, localhost, backend, appwrite

I have set up Appwrite locally for my Flutter app project and encountered an issue despite configuring my user limit as unlimited in the Appwrite dashboard panel. Whenever I attempt to perform user-related actions, such as user registration or authentication, I receive the error message

`The current project has exceeded the maximum number of users. Please check your user limit in the Appwrite console.`

This error persists even though I have explicitly set the user limit to unlimited in the dashboard.

How can I resolve this error and ensure that my locally deployed Appwrite instance properly recognizes the unlimited user limit, allowing me to perform user-related actions without any restrictions?

Note: I have already verified that my Appwrite dashboard panel displays the correct unlimited user limit setting for my project.

this is my endpoint :

```
static const endPoint = "http://localhost/v1";
```

and this is a screenshot from Appwrite console :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you've called the `client.setProject()` and the project ID you've passed is valid. If the project is omitted, the request may be an attempt to create a Console user, which would be rejected.